# {Which | what} songs {of | from} Rammstein do you like the {most | best}?

Tags: word-choice, questions

> Which songs of Rammstein do you like the most?
>
> Which songs from Rammstein do you like the most?

Are these two sentences correct? Also, can I say ''...do you like the best?" instead of "...the most?"

What about this:

> What are the songs of/from Rammstein you like the most/best?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you rearrange a bit:

> Which of Rammstein's songs do you like the best/most?

This would be a very natural phrasing. Whether you use best or most is completely up to you. There's no preference as far as I can tell.

You could also say

> What/Which Rammstein song/s do you like the best/most.

The singular what/song would give you a single song and the plural which/songs will ask for a list.

The options you have would likely be understood by most but they're a bit wordy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't know why you edited the post. "Rammstein" is the correct way to spell the name of the band.

Comment: Actually, [there ***is*** a fairly clear-cut established idiomatic preference](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you+like+best%2Cyou+like+most%2Cyou+like+the+best%2Cyou+like+the+most&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20like%20best%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20like%20most%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20like%20the%20best%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20like%20the%20most%3B%2Cc0) in favour of *Which do you **like best***. But that doesn't mean ***most*** or versions with the article ***the*** are in any way "less acceptable". They're all fine.

Comment: @Bora The Wikipedia article spells it with one m. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rammstein ... Or it did when I looked at it earlier... I swear I checked.